# Linear combination of independent poisson random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

We know that if $X_1$  and $X_2$ are independent random variables such that  $ X_1 \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1) $ and $X_2 \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_2)$ that $X_1+X_2 \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$

Is there any result about a linear combination of two independent poisson random variables $a_{1} X_1+a_2 X_2$ where $a_1, a_2 \in \mathcal{R}$?

Comment: This question has been asked before (though I cannot find it) and the answer is No: not much can be said, even in the case when $a_1$ and $a_2$ are restricted to be integers rather than arbitrary numbers in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I agree but my main aim is to decompose a Poisson process into a linear decomposition of two Poisson processes that are independent that is why I want to know if there are any clues or it is impossible.

Comment: @user144209 Have you looked at [infinite divisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) of Poisson processes?

Comment: yes, but the infinite divisibility of Poisson process is related to the special case where $a_1=a_2$ what if $a_1 \neq a_2$.

Comment: If you want to decompose a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ into two independent Poisson processes of rates $\lambda_1 > 0$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda-\lambda_1 > 0$, create a sequence of iid Bernoulli random variables $B_i$ with parameter $p = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda}$ and assign the $i$-th arrival in the base process to sub-process #1 or #2 according as $B_i = 1$ or $B_i = 0$. Note: the sequence of Bernoulli random variables needs to be independent of the Poisson process too.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What if he included the restriction on $a_1$ and $a_2$ so that $E[a_1X_1+a_2X_2]=var(a_1X_1+a_2X_2)$?

Comment: I did that but the problem we are not sure that we have integer value for the new process, we should add this constraint.

Answer (score 8):

If $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $Y=cX$, then $\mathbf{E}Y = c \lambda \neq \mathbf{Var} Y = c^2 \lambda$.

Comment: What if he included the restriction $\frac{a_1-a_1^2}{a_2-a_2^2}=\frac{E[X_2]}{E[X_1]}$? (This restriction came from setting $E[a_1X_1+a_2X_2]=var(a_1X_1+a_2X_2)$)

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathbb{E}e^{t(a_1X_1+a_2X_2)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda/a_1}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda/a_2}}=\frac{1}{1-a_1/a_2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda/a_1}}+\frac{1}{1-a_2/a_1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda/a_2}}$$Taking the inverse Laplace transform you'll find the pdf of $a_1X_1+a_2X_2$.