# What is the distribution of a sum of constants times Poissons

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, poisson-distribution

I have three independent random variables:

$X_i$~$Poisson(i)$,  $i=1,2,3$

I have no clue how find the distribution of the sum if I multiply them by some positive constant, say like:

$S= \sum_iiX_i$

for $i=1,2,3$

Without the constants I can just sum up the parameters since they are independent, then S will be:

$S$~$Poisson(6)$

But with the constants out front of each X, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: These will no longer be poisson, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746760/prove-that-a-constant-multiplied-by-a-poisson-random-variable-is-not-poisson).

Comment: Right, so i'm after how to start the convolution.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139124/linear-combination-of-independent-poisson-random-variables) for the $a_1X_1+a_2X_2$ case

Comment: so try with the MGF's?

Comment: Seems like it.  Stats.stackexchange talks about a similar problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49649/the-weighted-sum-of-two-independent-poisson-random-variables) without any clear (to me) answers.